# Configuring subdomain on Apache2 as an alias for subfolder

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

If I try to access my ownCloud service under `home.example.com/owncloud/` it's working.

I'm able to set the *mod_rewrite* rule to access the same service under `cloud.example.com` which is a CNAME for `home.example.com`, but this causes the browser just to be "redirected" to `cloud.example.com/owncloud/` (so this address is visible in the address bar).

What I want to achieve is to access the ownCloud instance which is in the sub folder under root of `cloud.example.com`. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you add to your question your mod_rewrite rule? I am having a bit of a hard time understanding your question, though I do not think it is your fault. Perhaps the pieces will come together when I see the code. At the very least, it will be necessary for anyone to answer your question properly anyhow. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide your virtual host configuration.   Do you have a virtual host for each subdomain or are you serving all your sites out of the default catch all virtual host?

Comment: Hello, I've solved this issue by setting up the virtual hosts on my server instead of creating a rewrite rule. After creating a virtual host with ServerName cloud.example.com in the config file located under /etc/apache2/sites-available/ I was able to connect to my website directly by using the CNAME cloud.example.com. Thank you for all helpful tips!

Comment: This question has a solution - Krzysztof found it himself, creating a VirtualHost. I'd say, any experienced Apache admin will have known the answer in no time ... So I don't quite understand why anyone should have considered the question unclear.